# Restrict access to a nested shared folder in Server 2008R2 file share

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, ntfs

Server 2008 R2 VM as a member server set up as a file server.

Situation: We have a contractor that needs read access to a nested folder in a shared directory in a domain environment.  How do I go about allowing that user access to files in a share directory while removing traverse rights?

Comment: Why do you want to remove traverse directory rights? If they don't have list contents or read, it doesn't matter...

Comment: Scratch that, traverse needs to be there.  Thanks MDMarra

Answer (score 4):

If you want to give access to a subfolder of shared directory, you have two options.

1. At a minimum, give `traverse folder / execute file` permissions to the root of the share and all parent folders of the subfolder you wish to grant access to.

   - If you wish, you can deny (or not grant) the `list folder / read data` permissions to other subfolders in the share.

     - We do this for our redirected user My Documents folders, so every user can access `\\DFSroot\Users\`, but can only see or access `\\DFSroot\Users\[their username]\`.  The value of prohibiting people from even seeing the other folders is questionable, IMO, but it's not that much extra work either.
2. Create a new share in the subfolder, grant the desired permissions and access it through that new share.

If you really want to deny `traverse folder / execute file` permissions higher up in the directory tree, you have to use option #2.  I would argue that #2 is probably the better option in general, because it's more visible and therefore, more likely to get cleaned up after the fact than a group of ACLs that aren't displayed unless you go looking.

Comment: You can do this without Deny by making the traverse ACE for "This folder only"